# implementation of #define and #ifdef in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am new for monoTouch. I have a file called "TargetConditions.h" in Objective-C. I am Trying use #define derivatives from "TargetConditions.h". But, I am not able to get these things into MonoTouch. Here is the list of things,

```
#define TARGET_OS_MAC 1
#define TARGET_OS_WIN32 0
#define TARGET_OS_UNIX 0
#define TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED 0
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE 1 
#define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR 1

#ifdef __MACH__
#define TARGET_RT_MAC_MACHO 1
#define TARGET_RT_MAC_CFM 0
#else
#define TARGET_RT_MAC_MACHO 0
#define TARGET_RT_MAC_CFM 1
#endif
```

How to integrate all the #define values into MonoTouch?
Please help me out from this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace these with constant definitions in a class.

```
public const int TARGET_OS_MAC = 1; 
public const int TARGET_OS_WIN32 = 0; 
public const int TARGET_OS_UNIX = 0; 
public const int TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED = 0; 
public const int TARGET_OS_IPHONE = 1;  
public const int TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR = 1; 

#if __MACH__ 
    public const int TARGET_RT_MAC_MACHO = 1; 
    public const int TARGET_RT_MAC_CFM = 0; 
#else 
    public const int TARGET_RT_MAC_MACHO = 0; 
    public const int TARGET_RT_MAC_CFM = 1; 
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks ctacke, I am able to declare these variables. But, i am not able to declare the following line of code, #define defined(__ppc64__). If you have any idea about this please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean `#if defined(ppc64)`?  Then it's #if ppc64.